# many htaccess files, same IP restrictions

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, .htaccess, web-hosting

On my webserver, some folders (like wp-admin/ wp-login.php...) or websites (dev.company.net) are restricted to my IP addresses.

Home, home ipv6, VPN, office, office IPv6.

```
<Files wp-login.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
allow from 88.222.222.88
allow from 92.92.92.92
allow from 2001:DB8:123:5fcc::/64
allow from 2001:DB8:8ae:e6c4::/64
</Files>
```

My home and office change regularly and I must go around all my htaccess files to gain access again.

Would you see a way of having it in only one place? I could make a `ln -s` but these .htaccess files often have other informations inside, since in strategic points.

I have access to apache config as well but this is Mass Virtual Hosting, I don't have any `<directory>` or `<location>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [Include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include) option to load your access config from a central file.

Another option would be some (dynamic) DNS entry for these IP addresses that you update when they change:

```
allow from myhost.dynds.org
....
```

Comment: oh I wonder if I add all the "A" and "AAAA" records in my DNS with all my IP like `my-secret-addresses.mydomain.com` if it would make it! it would be so convenient! thanks a lot

Comment: it didn't make it, as shown in [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/89984/htaccess-allow-from-hostname) this is a PTR resolution I think... sad it would have been awesome

Comment: I accept this answer even if it doesn't work in my case: this is a mass virtual host. Which means I have only one conf file for an unlimited number of virtual host ( /var/www/virtualhosts/%1/ ). And %1 is www.mywebsite.com .  I think only .htaccess could do it.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, I accepted @Sven 's answer even if it doesn't work in my case: this is a mass virtual host. Which means I have only one conf file for an unlimited number of virtual host ( /var/www/virtualhosts/%1/ ).

Actually I decided to create a folder `/home/websites/access/` where I create symbolic links

```
ln -s /home/websites/websites01/.htaccess /home/websites/access/htaccess.website01
```

So when I change I won't be looking all around my harddisk

When the file contain only the IP restriction I have one file and just use a symbolic link to it

```
ln -s /home/websites/access/htaccess.ip-restrict /home/websites/websites02/.htaccess
```

and `/home/websites/access/htaccess.ip-restrict`:

```
<Files wp-login.php>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  allow from 88.222.222.88
  allow from 92.92.92.92
  allow from 2001:DB8:123:5fcc::/64
  allow from 2001:DB8:8ae:e6c4::/64
</Files>
```

I hope that I won't forget any website when the next change happen only 6 months later and I dont remember everything.